# Mediawiki MySQL have high cpu loading sometimes

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

Mediawiki MySQL have high cpu loading sometimes.

We host a mediawiki, it have around 50 person online

version is 1.31

here is LocaleSettings.php content

```
<?php
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.31.0
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See includes/DefaultSettings.php for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
        exit;
}


## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "MyWiki";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
#$wgServer = "https://wikidecode.org";
$wgServer = "https://xxxxxxx.com";

## The URL path to static resources (images, scripts, etc.)
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;

## The URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo = "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/wiki.png";

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@xxxxxxx.com";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@xxxxxxx.com";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "127.0.0.1";
$wgDBname = "mediawikidb";
$wgDBuser = "mediawikidb";
$wgDBpassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";
$wgSQLMode = null;

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

## Shared memory settings
#$wgUseGzip = true;
$wgEnableSidebarCache = true;
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_MEMCACHED;
$wgParserCacheType = CACHE_MEMCACHED; # optional
$wgMessageCacheType = CACHE_MEMCACHED; # optional
$wgMemCachedServers = array( "127.0.0.1:11211" );
#$wgUseLocalMessageCache = true;
$wgSessionsInObjectCache = true; # optional
$wgSessionCacheType = CACHE_MEMCACHED; # optional

# File cache
$wgUseFileCache = true;
#$wgFileCacheDirectory = "/var/www/mediawiki/file-cache";
$wgFileCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

# NO DB HITS!
# Refer to https://techwelkin.com/slow-mediawiki-optimize-to-enhance-performance-part-1
$wgDisableCounters = false;
$wgHitcounterUpdateFreq = 500;
$wgMiserMode = true;
#$wgJobRunRate = 0; // Set a cronjob via "crontab -e" with "0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mediawiki/maintenance/runJobs.php > /var/log/runJobs.log 2>&1"


## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publically accessible from the web.
$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = true;
#$wgUseImageMagick = true;
#$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from https://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;
$wgRunJobsAsync = true;

# Periodically send a pingback to https://www.mediawiki.org/ with basic data
# about this MediaWiki instance. The Wikimedia Foundation shares this data
# with MediaWiki developers to help guide future development efforts.
$wgPingback = false;

## If you use ImageMagick (or any other shell command) on a
## Linux server, this will need to be set to the name of an
## available UTF-8 locale
$wgShellLocale = "C.UTF-8";


# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./languages/data/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "zh";

$wgSecretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

# Changing this will log out all existing sessions.
$wgAuthenticationTokenVersion = "1";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, ie 'vector', 'monobook':
#$wgDefaultSkin = "minerva";
$wgDefaultSkin = "Timeless";

# Enabled skins.
# The following skins were automatically enabled:
wfLoadSkin( 'MonoBook' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Timeless' );
wfLoadSkin( 'Vector' );


# Enabled extensions. Most of the extensions are enabled by adding
# wfLoadExtensions('ExtensionName');
# to LocalSettings.php. Check specific extension documentation for more details.
# The following extensions were automatically enabled:
wfLoadExtension( 'CategoryTree' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CiteThisPage' );
wfLoadExtension( 'CodeEditor' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
#wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Interwiki' );
wfLoadExtension( 'LocalisationUpdate' );
wfLoadExtension( 'MultimediaViewer' );
wfLoadExtension( 'OATHAuth' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ParserFunctions' );
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Poem' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Renameuser' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ReplaceText' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SpamBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi' );
wfLoadExtension( 'TitleBlacklist' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Babel' );

wfLoadExtension( 'cldr' );

wfLoadExtension( 'CleanChanges' );
$wgCCTrailerFilter = true;
$wgCCUserFilter = false;
$wgDefaultUserOptions['usenewrc'] = 1;

wfLoadExtension( 'LocalisationUpdate' );
$wgLocalisationUpdateDirectory = "$IP/cache";

require_once "$IP/extensions/Translate/Translate.php";
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-messagereview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-groupreview'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['translate-import'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['pagetranslation'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['translate-manage'] = true;
$wgTranslateDocumentationLanguageCode = 'qqq';
$wgExtraLanguageNames['qqq'] = 'Message documentation'; # No linguistic content. Used for documenting messages

wfLoadExtension( 'UniversalLanguageSelector' );
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' );

wfLoadExtension( 'Scribunto' );
#$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luastandalone';
#$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luastandalone']['cpuLimit'] = 'ulimit';
#$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luastandalone']['memoryLimit'] = 209715200; # bytes
$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luasandbox';
$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luasandbox']['cpuLimit'] = 'ulimit';
$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luasandbox']['memoryLimit'] = 209715200; # bytes

wfLoadExtension( 'Nuke' );

#wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' );
// Enable by default for everybody
# $wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-enable'] = 1;

// Optional: Set VisualEditor as the default for anonymous users
// otherwise they will have to switch to VE
# $wgDefaultUserOptions['visualeditor-editor'] = "visualeditor";

// Don't allow users to disable it
# $wgHiddenPrefs[] = 'visualeditor-enable';

# Parsoid fir Visual Editor

$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
    // URL to the Parsoid instance
    // Use port 8142 if you use the Debian package
    //'url' => 'http://wikidecode.org:8142',
    'url' => 'http://xxxxxxx.com:8142',
    // Parsoid "domain", see below (optional)
    //'domain' => 'localhost',
    // Parsoid "prefix", see below (optional)
    //'prefix' => 'localhost'
);

# Wikibase
$wgEnableWikibaseRepo = true;
$wgEnableWikibaseClient = true;
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/repo/Wikibase.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/repo/ExampleSettings.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/client/WikibaseClient.php";
require_once "$IP/extensions/Wikibase/client/ExampleSettings.php";

# Mobile responsive display
wfLoadExtension( 'MobileFrontend' );
$wgMFAutodetectMobileView = true;

wfLoadSkin( 'MinervaNeue' );
$wgMFDefaultSkinClass = 'SkinMinerva';
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
# Auto confirm threshold
$wgAutoConfirmCount=20;

# Tidy # Fix the problem that infobox will show <td? </td>
$wgUseTidy=true;

# Permission (need to comment out to make Visual Editor work)
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;  # Disable reading by anonymous users
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['writeapi'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createpage'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createtalk'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;  # Prevent new user registrations except by sysops

# Debugging
#$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;
#$wgShowDBErrorBacktrace = true;

#$wgShowSQLErrors = true;
#$wgDebugDumpSql = true;

#$wgDebugComments = true;
$wgDebugLogFile = "/var/log/mediawiki/debug-{$wgDBname}.log";

$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;
$wgMaxShellMemory = 204800; # in KB

# TemplateStyle
wfLoadExtension( 'TemplateStyles' );

#Youtube
wfLoadExtension( 'YouTube' );

#Embedded Video
wfLoadExtension( 'EmbedVideo' );

# Permission to Hide history
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['deletelogentry'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['deleterevision'] = true;

# Notice 
# $wgSiteNotice = "Internal..."

# Upload picture option
# allow upload by URL
$wgAllowCopyUploads = true;
$wgCopyUploadsFromSpecialUpload = true;

# Increase Session timeout
$wgCookieExpiration = 86400;
$wgExtendedLoginCookieExpiration = null;


# Proxy WWW
#$wgUseSquid = true;
#$wgSquidServers = [ 'x.x.x.x' ];
#$wgSquidServersNoPurge = [ 'x.x.x.x' ];

# 貢獻得分
require_once "$IP/extensions/ContributionScores/ContributionScores.php";
$wgContribScoreIgnoreBots = true;          // Exclude Bots from the reporting - Can be omitted.
$wgContribScoreIgnoreBlockedUsers = true;  // Exclude Blocked Users from the reporting - Can be omitted.
$wgContribScoresUseRealName = true;        // Use real user names when available - Can be omitted. Only for MediaWiki 1.19 and later.
$wgContribScoreDisableCache = true;       // Set to true to disable cache for parser function and inclusion of table.

//Each array defines a report - 7,50 is "past 7 days" and "LIMIT 50" - Can be omitted.
$wgContribScoreReports = array(
    array(7,20),
    array(30,20),
    array(0,20));

# Change default user behavior
## Add pages the user edits to their watchlist by default
$wgDefaultUserOptions['watchdefault'] = 0;  // 不將更改的page加入監視列表

# 允許外部連結顯示圖片
$wgAllowExternalImages=true;

# 開啟濫用日誌
wfLoadExtension( 'AbuseFilter' );
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['abusefilter-modify'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['abusefilter-log-detail'] = true;
##$wgGroupPermissions['*']['abusefilter-view'] = true;
##$wgGroupPermissions['*']['abusefilter-log'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['abusefilter-private'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['abusefilter-modify-restricted'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['abusefilter-revert'] = true;

# 防止用戶名使用非格式化字串
#wfLoadExtension( 'AntiSpoof' );
#$wgSharedTables[] = 'spoofuser';

# 允許HTML img tag
$wgAllowImageTag=true;

# 必須email驗證
#$wgEmailConfirmToEdit=true;

# Lockdown Permission
wfLoadExtension( 'Lockdown' );
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_TEMPLATE]['*'] = ['bureaucrat'];
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_TEMPLATE]['read'] = ['*'];

# 網站維護....
#$wgReadOnly = 'Dumping Database, Access will be restored shortly';

# 打開舉報 (註冊用戶可以舉報，管理員處理)
wfLoadExtension( 'Report' );

# 可以看見誰正在監視那個page
wfLoadExtension( 'WhoIsWatching' );
$whoiswatching_nametype = "RealName";
# $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['addpagetoanywatchlist'] = true;
# $wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['seepagewatchers'] = true;

# 追蹤某個使用者的進出狀況
#require_once "$IP/extensions/StalkerLog/StalkerLog.php";
#$wgGroupPermissions['*']['stalkerlog-view-log'] = false;
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['stalkerlog-view-log'] = true;

# Who is online
wfLoadExtension( 'WhosOnline' );
$wgWhosOnlineShowAnons = true;

# 關閉page view counter
# $wgDisableCounters = true;

#wfLoadExtension( 'MatomoAnalytics' );
#$wgMatomoAnalyticsServerURL=false;
#$wgMatomoAnalyticsTokenAuth=false;

# Check User IP (blocking by IP range)
wfLoadExtension( 'CheckUser' );
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['checkuser'] = true;
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['checkuser-log'] = true;
$wgAddGroups['bureaucrat'][] = 'checkuser';
$wgRemoveGroups['bureaucrat'][] = 'checkuser';


# Local S3 for image
# https://github.com/edwardspec/mediawiki-aws-s3
#wfLoadExtension( 'AWS' );

// Configure AWS credentials.
// THIS IS NOT NEEDED if your EC2 instance has an IAM instance profile.
#$wgAWSCredentials = [
#       'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
#       'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
#       'token' => false
#];

#$wgAWSRegion = 'us-west-2'; # Oregon

// Replace <something> with the name of your S3 bucket, e.g. wonderfulbali234.
#$wgAWSBucketName = "mediawiki-uploads";
#$wgUploadDirectory = "$IP/s3mnt";
#$wgUploadPath = "$wgScriptPath/s3mnt";

# Anti-Robot Mechanism
#wfLoadExtension( 'ConfirmEdit' );
#$wgGroupPermissions['*'            ]['skipcaptcha'] = false; // Default
#$wgGroupPermissions['user'         ]['skipcaptcha'] = false; // Default
#$wgGroupPermissions['autoconfirmed']['skipcaptcha'] = false; // Default
#$wgGroupPermissions['bot'          ]['skipcaptcha'] = true;  // Default: registered bots
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop'        ]['skipcaptcha'] = true;  // Default

#$wgCaptchaTriggers['edit'] = false;            // Trigger while editing a page
#$wgCaptchaTriggers['create'] = true;          // Default: Trigger while creating a page
#$wgCaptchaTriggers['addurl'] = true;          // Default: Trigger while ading a url
#$wgCaptchaTriggers['createaccount'] = true;   // Default: Trigger while registering
#$wgCaptchaTriggers['badlogin'] = true;        // Default: Trigger while bad login

# Echo to users
wfLoadExtension( 'Echo' );

# Delete a Page permanently
wfLoadExtension( 'DeletePagesForGood' );
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['deleteperm'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['deleteperm'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['bureaucrat']['deleteperm'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['deleteperm'] = false;

# Gadgets edit permission
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['gadgets-edit'] = true;
#$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['gadgets-definition-edit'] = true;

# Addthis
#require_once "$IP/extensions/AddThis/AddThis.php";
#$wgAddThisMain=false;
#$wgAddThisSidebar=false;

# Related Articles
#wfLoadExtension( 'RelatedArticles' );
#$wgRelatedArticlesFooterWhitelistedSkins = ['vector', 'timeless', 'minerva', 'monobook'];

$wgULSGeoService = 'https://freegeoip.app/json/8.8.8.8?callback=?';


# New namespace for private pages
// Define constants for my additional namespaces.
define("NS_FOO", 3000); // This MUST be even.
define("NS_FOO_TALK", 3001); // This MUST be the following odd integer.

// Add namespaces.
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO] = "Foo";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_FOO_TALK] = "Foo_talk"; // Note underscores in the namespace name.

$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_FOO] = array( 'editfoo' ); // permission "editfoo" required to edit the foo namespace
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_FOO] = true;            // subpages enabled for the foo namespace
$wgGroupPermissions['staff']['editfoo'] = true;      // permission "editfoo" granted to users in the "staff" group
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_FOO]['read'] = ['staff'];
```

sometimes mysqld cost all cpu resource, and nginx show 504 gateway time-out.
here is part of mysql slow query log:

```
# Time: 2018-12-04T17:13:53.679634Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id: 82845
# Query_time: 3.868103  Lock_time: 0.000066 Rows_sent: 6  Rows_examined: 14
SET timestamp=1543943633;
SELECT /* SearchMySQL::searchInternal  */  page_id,page_namespace,page_title  FROM `page`,`searchindex`    WHERE (page_id=si_page) AND ( MATCH(si_text) AGAINST('+\"u8e7ae80 u8c2b7 u8e696b9 u8e8bebe\" ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AND page_namespace IN ('0','120')   LIMIT 20;
# Time: 2018-12-04T17:13:57.542743Z
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id: 82845
# Query_time: 3.861802  Lock_time: 0.000104 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 14
SET timestamp=1543943637;
SELECT /* SearchMySQL::searchInternal  */  COUNT(*) as c  FROM `page`,`searchindex`    WHERE (page_id=si_page) AND ( MATCH(si_text) AGAINST('+\"u8e7ae80 u8c2b7 u8e696b9 u8e8bebe\" ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) AND page_namespace IN ('0','120');
```

I'm not sure what is main problem, is MySQL setting or Mediawiki or just have to upgrade hardware?

I already tried change mysql setting many times, it didn't fix.

here is my mysqld.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 512M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 32
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_type        = 0
query_cache_limit       = 2M
query_cache_size        = 0
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

#log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#add
table_open_cache = 432
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
```

hardware is Amazon EC2 c5.large

OS version: Ubuntu 16.04.5

MySQL version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper

Comment: With 50 persons on line, FIRST my.cnf change should be  thread_cache_size=64 to avoid thread breakdown/recreate.  May be monitored with SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'threads_created' at the end of your working day, DAILY.

Comment: Ram for SQL server is 8GB now. (when it leaggy, it is 4GB)

(A) 
https://pastebin.com/WFqRHC2b
https://pastebin.com/QUrW4EwG
https://pastebin.com/dX2mQP5T

(B) https://pastebin.com/PY02dG2D
(C) https://pastebin.com/yY9yRZcZ
(D) https://pastebin.com/tkYiMAdL

I will change thread_cache_size to 64 now.
and provide htop detail when busy.

Comment: in addition to htop, still need  ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, when you can post the results.  Thanks for data posted a couple of hours ago.   Thanks

Comment: Please confirm storage type  A) rotating B) SSD C) NVME or something else.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found reason.
It maybe MyISAM engine lock problem,
search index default is using MyISAM engine.
I try to change engine to innoDB.
(but your MySQL version should higher than 5.6)

ref: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Searchindex_table

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS - With the information available at this time, consider these suggestions for your Performance Group [mysqld] section, please

```
innodb_io_capacity=1800  # from 200 to use more of available IOPS
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads RPS from ~5 per SECOND
open_files_limit=16384  # from 1024 to accommodate high volume file activity
table_open_cache=10000  # from 431 to reduce opened_tables RPS of more than 2
```

At Linux command prompt, ulimit -n 24576    to dynamically increase Open File limit from 1024

For this Linux change to persist over shutdown/restart refer to this url

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Your specifics may be slightly different due to OS version.

Good Luck.

For additional suggestions, view profile, Network profile for contact information.